# How to set video quality of a embedded YouTube video in LaTeX Beamer

Tags: video, youtube, beamer

I am trying to include a YouTube video in my LaTeX beamer slide and want to control the video quality. The default setting is 360p and I want 720p.

Here is the code I use.

```
\includemedia[
width=.8\linewidth,
totalheight=1.5\linewidth,
activate=pageopen,
flashvars={
modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar
&autohide=1 % controlbar autohide
&showinfo=1 % title and other info before start
&rel=0 % no related videos after end
}
]{}{https://www.youtube.com/v/PEqfyIGSKiE}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way out.

Changing the address to the video from

```
{https://www.youtube.com/v/PEqfyIGSKiE}
```

to

```
{https://www.youtube.com/v/PEqfyIGSKiE?vq=hd720}
```

will do the trick.